# can dev c++ be installed on mac OS X yosemite?

Tags: macos

I need to insert jpeg images in my C++ program. I tried doing it on turbo C++ and code blocks using `graphic.h` header but it didn't work. So someone told me that dev C++ supports graphics well and inserting pictures can be done easily. So I wonder if dev C++ can run on mac and also I am a new mac user.

Comment: No, thank God. BTW, `graphic.h`? We're a little past the days of MS-DOS.... have you considered using XCode, and modern ways of showing graphics?

Comment: Start the **App Store** program (it's in *Applications*) and search in there for *Xcode* - it's free, install it.